# Is there an ability to limit the cypher query results by timelimit?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

I'm running quite time consuming cypher queries in production. The query does not need to have all of the matched results, but rather should complete in a specified timelimit. If there are 10000 possible matches, it is ok to go with 5000, rather than have neo4j transaction timeout, that is small.

Is it possible to specify the timelimit in the cypher query, like in Gremlin timeLimit step?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the APOC procedure [apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll_while](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_further_functions) to implement a time limit.

The procedure's first parameter must be a Cypher query that will stop the procedure when the query returns `0` or `NULL` or `FALSE`. That query has access to a `$previous` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/parameters/) that contains the previous value returned by the query (or `NULL` if this is the first time the query is being called). The query's return value must be named `loop`.

The second parameter must be a Cypher query that returns all the items (e.g., nodes) to be worked on, and the third parameter must be a Cypher query that works on each item returned by the second parameter. The named values returned by the second parameter's Cypher query (e.g., named `foo`) are available to the third parameter's Cypher query (e.g., as `$foo`).

The fourth parameter is the "batch size", the number of items that the third parameter should work on before the first parameter is asked again to decide whether to stop.

In the following example query (for a made-up use case), I assume that `$duration` (the approximate max number of milliseconds to wait for an answer) and `$batchSize` (the size of each batch) are passed as parameters (to the outer Cypher query):

```
WITH timestamp() + $duration AS endTime
CALL apoc.periodic.rock_n_roll_while(
  'RETURN timestamp() < endTime AS loop',
  'MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p',
  'MATCH (p) WHERE p = $p SET p.lastname = p.name',
  $batchSize)
```

The `duration` is approximate since we only check if the time limit has been met after every batch. For more accurate time limits, make the `batchSize` smaller.

The original version of the above query (with no time limit) would have been something like this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
SET p.lastname = p.name
```

Comment: Great! Thank you a lot! And if only the part of the data was updated, when the transaction timeout occured, this part won't be rolled back?